# Magento product import causing corrupt data

Tags: magento

I have a csv which has two columns 'sku' and a custom field which is a string value.

When I import it works in as much as the custom field values are attached to the product but it is causing other issues.

On some products the tax class id is missing, whilst on others the shipping weight is missing.  In one category all of the 'brand' attribute values are missing.

I have never seen this before.

I have checked the csv for wierd characters etc and all is fine.

The only thing I could see was that the custom field mentioned contains commas - but I am sure that this should be fine as it has worked before.

Answer (score 0):

this may be your solution, I was having the same problem recently. Make sure you are saving as character encoding UTF-8. If you are using OpenOffice (Xcel formats CSV wrong), when you do "Save As" tick the Edit filter settings" and then once you click save you'll be given the option to save as UTF-8. For Xcel just Google it.